# Test that mysql shell with --ssl-mode=REQUIRED to given --host REALLY works without first providing username, password, database-name?

Tags: security, encryption, mysql, ssl

I'm looking for a possibility in the **mysql client** to only test whether the `--ssl-mode=REQUIRED` directive to a given `--host` **is 100% ensured, without potentially spoiling username, password and database name** in plaintext through the Internet. Running that mode with an argument like: `--ssl--check-handshake-only-then-disconnect-and-report`.

This is for a scenario where in regards to one's webhost:

- one has no proper/available/reliable documentation on availability of SSL on the server,
- and/or no or only complicated access to the mysql server and its configuration info.

---

After my research so far, I think there is **no possibility for a 100% riskless SSL/TLS handshake test run** which is **obviously riskless as it works without supplying username, password, databasename**.

The documentation for [--ssl-mode=REQUIRED](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/connection-options.html#option_general_ssl-mode) addresses this just very plain and briefly:

> REQUIRED: Establish an encrypted connection if the server supports encrypted connections. The connection attempt fails if an encrypted connection cannot be established.

One simply has to trust the mysql client (aka "shell") that it really operates in that order:

1. make sure that `--ssl-mode=REQUIRED` works in the given situation, else exit prematurely with an explicit error message.
2. only when the handshake and encryption negotiation worked out fine, the client submits the supplied username, password, database-name.
3. And that no new developer will ever introduces a bug exactly in that condition check...

- That may be sufficient for versed/everyday users, who know and trust their mysql client and setup.
- But sub-optimal for new users or need-to-be skeptics, who really need a possibility for a 100% risk free check.

A truly "riskless connection/handshake testing mode" which obviously is riskless because it also works without submitting any concrete credentials, would be very re-assuring.

- Before I register at https://bugs.mysql.com and submit a feature request there
- I ask here, whether there may be a possibility I'm not aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to test that the client throws an error when SSL can't be established, then a quick and dirty way is to combine these two:

- just connect with a bogus username and password
- force the client to fail ssl handshake with a bad cipher like `--ssl-cipher SEED-SHA`

You should always see the error for "SSL failure" and not "bad password". Try with `--ssl-mode=REQUIRED` on and off to verify whether it throws an error or falls back to cleartext.

---

If you want to check whether the server supports SSL (and to what degree), then something like nmap is going to be better. Make sure you have an updated version of nmap, then, use something like this to check the SSL status for example:

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers MyServerName -p 3306
```

And if nothing else, you can always verify that connections don't send credentials before SSL with a packet capture / wireshark, though it has a learning curve.

---

Like you mention, this is simple if you can work with whoever controls the server, with options like:

- use certificate-based authentication, so no secrets are ever transferred
- require ssl on the server side, (which should be demanded if it's internet-facing)
- control connections with VPN or SSH before connecting to MySql

but it's not always possible

---

#### Results of `nmap` - This feels like the proper tool for the job!

```
nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers  customerid-mysql.services.mywebhost.com -p 3306
Starting Nmap 7.93 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2022-12-16 01:39 CET
Nmap scan report for customerid-mysql.services.mywebhost.com (XXX.XX.X.XX)
Host is up (0.016s latency).
rDNS record for XXX.XX.X.XX: web20.mywebhost.com

PORT     STATE SERVICE
3306/tcp open  mysql
| ssl-enum-ciphers: 
|   TLSv1.2: 
|     ciphers: 
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (dh 2048) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 4096) - A
|       TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 4096) - A
|     compressors: 
|       NULL
|     cipher preference: client
|     warnings: 
|       Key exchange (dh 2048) of lower strength than certificate key
|       Key exchange (secp256r1) of lower strength than certificate key
|_  least strength: A

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 3.23 seconds
```

#### Results of `mysql` combined with `--ssl-cipher` and `--ssl-mode`

```
$ mysql --ssl-cipher SEED-SHA  -h customerID-mysql.services.mywebhost.com -u fakeUser -p --ssl-mode=DISABLED 
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'fakeUser'@'XX.XXX.XX.XX' (using password: YES)
```

- ❌ Server accepts plaintext.
- ✅ But we spoiled only bogus data.
- ✅ No harm done. Max risk established.

```
$ mysql --ssl-cipher SEED-SHA  -h customerID-mysql.services.mywebhost.com -u fakeUser -p --ssl-mode=REQUIRED 
Enter password: 
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

- ✅ Server aborts with bad cipher.
- ℹ️ From theory we know that this kicks in before credentials are sent.
- ✅ So this is a good enough pre-test, for those who have the knowhow.

```
$ mysql --ssl-cipher SEED-SHA  -h customerID-mysql.services.mywebhost.com -u fakeUser -p --ssl-mode=PREFERRED
Enter password: 
ERROR 2026 (HY000): SSL connection error: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

- ✅ Also when we tempt the server with PREFERRED but provide a bad cipher, the server takes the safe choice and terminates.
- ✅ Feels chilling. Also I do not understand why --ssl-cipher SEED-SHA is a bad cipher exactly and with which conditions this is tested.

```
$ mysql  -h customerID-mysql.services.mywebhost.com -u fakeUser -p --ssl-mode=REQUIRED 
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'fakeUser'@'77.119.77.94' (using password: YES)
```

- ❓ Not sure how to interpret this:
- ❌ Although I REQUIRED the protocol continues (at least submits the username, which luckily yet is only 'fakeUser'.
- ❓But was the password also sent in this request?

Comment: I add my response on bottom of your reply, b/c It needs more space and full formatting. Feel free to answer in the comments here, or also use the workaround to edit the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I'm accepting the answer. `nmap` from first sight seems to be definitely the tool to check which encryption support for a given port and protocol exist at a given host, without having studied it in more detail yet. Thanks! Using `mysql` with `--ssl-cipher` combined with `--ssl-mode= [ DISABLED | PREFERRED | REQUIRED ]` and with a risk free fake username and fake password but still running into the handshake error and not U/P error, seems to be a quick workaround for people knowing what they are doing/expecting!  But `nmap` is clearly the superior tool. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide an answer to the outcome that I marked with  "❓Not sure how to interpret this" ? Would be appreciated! For situations where the `mysql` shell is the only available tool it would be good to being able to interpret all outcomes of the test permutations, as provided above. Thanks!

Comment: @porg since SSL was required, I interpret that result as: an SSL connection was successfully established, and the password was sent (securely). Also, I picked SEED-SHA for throwing errors because it's old, very broken, and unlikely to be enabled on any server.

Comment: Again, the only way to be really 100% sure that `--ssl-mode=REQUIRED` does what you expect, is to do a packet capture yourself. However, unless you are a security researcher, I think you can trust the mysql client not to send plaintext. Otherwise, there are other ways to mess with or inspect the SSL itself with openSSL (which mysql uses in the background), or compiling the open-source client code yourself

Comment: Your interpretation of the outcome makes sense to me now! Due to the omission of the outdated `--ssl-cipher SEED-SHA` but still with the insistence `--ssl-mode=REQUIRED` a contemporary SSL-cipher could be chosen and the requirement was fulfilled and the process failed already at a later stage, namely the password verification, which already happened inside the SSL tunneling. Thanks got it now!